# Convert inline styles to css rules

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm interesting if there is a way to convert inline element styles to the css rules. The hardest part, I think, is to generate needed css-selectors. May be it's not possible at all, but may be there is a solution with js or php. Thank you.

For examle,

```
<div class="red" style="color: #red"></div>
<div style="color: #yellow"></div>
<div id="white" style="color: #white"></div>
```

will be converted, assuming classes and ids to

```
<style>
    div{color: #yellow}
    .red{color: #red}
    #white{color: #white}
</style>

<div class="red"></div>
<div></div>
<div id="white"></div>
```

I need this for my template generator, it preffered styles to be not inline, but in separate file or tag, so the original html code of blocks won't be changed, while editing colors, fonts, etc. I think, i explain clearly, cause english isn't my native language)

Comment: Do you mean automatically have all inline styles converted for a whole project or what?

Comment: Post your "CODE" in here. Also why would PHP come in a role here?

Comment: try `dreamweaver`. It will made a css file from inline css if you're looking for this.

Comment: Warning: `#yellow` will work but you'll get unexpected color. Even if there may be a tool that will make rules of inline styles, I'll not recommend you to use it. You cannot put HUMAN intelligence in it. That may apply the styles generically, which of course you don't want

Comment: @markus for a whole html page

Comment: @divy3993 because there is a library for html parsing, so i think, i can be usefull

Comment: @Kiyarash if dreamweaver had an web-api, may be, but it's not..so it's not a solution)

Comment: @Tushar Yes, i understand, that there will be a huge problem with generating right selectors, but i think the solution exists..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://extractcss.com, but as @Tushar pointed out, the yellow div won't work.

Try https://github.com/jonkemp/extract-css too, which looks promising.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this projects. Yellow was just for example, all colors will be HEX-values.

Comment: oh, i see..these services dont extract inline styles without ids or classes, but thank you for help

Comment: That's right, it won't create an ID or Class for you. Maybe the other one will be more intelligent. Anyway, thanks for accepting my answer.