# is there a package that turns inline styles to css classes

Tags: html, css, npm

Is there a package that if I pass

```html
<p style="width: 500px; height: 500px"> Hello World </p>
```

will return

```html
<p class="foo"> Hello World </p>
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: [Convert inline styles to css rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934342/convert-inline-styles-to-css-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JS to do this. Grab all the elements with a style tag

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[style]');
```

Loop through all elements, give them a random class and add the syntax in a style tag

```
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var rndClass = getUniqueRandomClass();

  var style = els[i].style;
  var returnStyle = "." + rndClass + "{" + style + "}";
  document.querySelector('style').textContent += returnStyle;

  els[i].classList.add(rndClass);
  els[i].removeAttribute("style");
}
```